# DbContext inside ViewModel class

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Due to the lack of lazy load implementation in Entity Framework Core 1.0, I need to access manually some entities inside my view models.

As a solution I'm passing the `DbContext` for each viewmodel I create, like this:

```
new ViewModels.Account.EditViewModel(Db);
```

Is there a way to get `DbContext` instance directly by viewmodel class ?

Comment: What are your view models - objects that you pass to your Razor view or something else?

Comment: Seems to be a bad practice have the dbContext within the ViewModel. What is your original problem?

Comment: You shouldn't really do that, it doesn't work well with the async nature of ASP.NET Core, because you can't await properties, which means the query will block the whole request, significantly hurting the performance of your ASP.NET Core WebApp. You may be better of explicitly creating specific view models for the view you want to display it on and do the projection in your repository